# Assign pk form URL to model's related field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested-urls

I would like to use the "nested" url `/customers/<id>/orders` to create new orders using `POST`. I would like to get the related order's `customer_id` based on the request's url `<id>`.

`Order` model has a `customer = ForgeinKey(Customer,..)` field that relates to the `Customer` model.

My approach so far is:

1. Creating an `OrderSerializer`
2. Using `create()` to create an Model object
3. Getting the customer id during creation from `self.context['request'].get_full_path()`, which return the full url path
4. Getting the customer object based on the customer id using

```
customer_id = self.context['request'].get_full_path().split('/')[2]
customers = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
```

5. Assigning the `customers.id` to the Order's `customer_id` field

This solution works but seems extremely dirty. Is there a better way?

Let me know if any more details are needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `create()` method of the serializer, one can access the pk using

```
self.context['view'].kwargs['pk']
```

So the above code becomes:

```
customer_id = self.context['view'].kwargs['pk']
customers = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this.

```
def create(self):
    customer_id = self.kwargs['id']
    customers = Customer.objects.get(id=customer_id)
```